# Django application works under runserver, but 404s under nginx

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

My Django app is running fine on my server when running it under "python manage.py runserver....." but when I run it under nginx/fastcgi I get a 404.

Here is the error message:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:  blah.youtrain.me/admin/ (I removed the http due to StackOverflow constraints for new account)
>   
>   Using the URLconf defined in youtrainme.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   
>   ^admin/doc/
>   ^admin/
>   
>   The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

No matter what page on my app I go to under nginx, it always displays the same error message: "The current URL, , didn't match any of these."

Under nginx, if I just go to blah.youtrain.me the Request URL above changes to: blah.youtrain.me// <--- note the trailing slash. However, under runserver, there is no trailing slash in the Request URL line. This might give some insight?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Here is my nginx config for this site:

> server
>       {
>       listen 80;
>       server_name blah.youtrain.me;
>       access_log /home/ytmadmin/public_html/blah.youtrain.me/log/access.log;
>       error_log /home/ytmadmin/public_html/blah.youtrain.me/log/error.log debug;
>       # rewrite rule - files
>       location ~* .+.>(xml|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf)
>           {
>           access_log off;
>     expires 30d;
>           break;
>           }
>       # python requests
>       location /
>           {
>           fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8010;
>           fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
>     fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
>     include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
>           }
>   }

And my urls.py

> from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
>   
>   from django.contrib import admin
>   admin.autodiscover()
>   
>   urlpatterns = patterns('',
>       (r'^$', 'main.views.index'),
>       (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
>   
>       # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
>       (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>   )

Comment: looks like you just have admin urls in your urls.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/134863/nginx-fastcgi-problems-with-django-double-slashes-in-url

Under nginx, I had to remove the following line from my nginx/conf/fastcgi_params file and all was well:

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;